# mySQL statement get last record

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the total of votes for each FANOF_ID (ex: Me). The problem is that a FAN can vote each day for the same FANOF_ID (ex: David Bowie RIP)

So each day I could vote for David Bowie as my favorite singer

```
ID  CREATED    FAN_ID FANOF_ID
15  2016-01-24 3      3
16  2016-01-25 3      3
17  2016-01-25 2      3
```

So from that example I should get a result of 2 fans for 'total' for FANOF_ID (3)

This is my actual SQL

```
SELECT
  distinct `fans_fanofvote`.`fan_id`,
  COUNT(`fans_fanofvote`.`fanof_id`) AS `total`
FROM `fans_fanofvote`
GROUP BY `fans_fanofvote`.`fanof_id`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

But it returns 3 records even if I use distinct on fan_id it wont work.  How can I get mySQL to do a distinct on FAN_ID

My SQL should return one record like that:

```
FANOF_ID TOTAL
3        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `COUNT(DISTINCT)`.  However, you have to be careful about what you are counting (`fan_id`) and what you are aggregating by `(fanof_id`):

```
SELECT fov.fanof_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT fov.fan_id) AS total
FROM fans_fanofvote fov
GROUP BY fov.fanof_id
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

Note that table aliases make the query easier to read.  And don't use back tick unless really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention expected output earlier so it was confusing.

```
SELECT
  `fans_fanofvote`.`fanof_id`,
  COUNT(`fans_fanofvote`.`fan_id`) AS `total`
FROM `fans_fanofvote`
GROUP BY `fans_fanofvote`.`fanof_id`
ORDER BY `total` DESC
```

Comment: If I do that I get 2 records since they are group by fan_id.

Comment: They are grouped by fan_id and fanod_id. Add some more records then check.

Comment: I did and I get a new record for each fan id

Answer (score 0):

Use count(distinct )

```
SELECT

   COUNT(distinct `fans_fanofvote`.`fanof_id`) AS `total`
FROM `fans_fanofvote`
GROUP BY `fans_fanofvote`.`fanof_id`
ORDER BY `tot
```